# Perl system command output visible when running from console but not visible when running through browser CGI

Tags: perl, cgi, system

I know there are similar questions answered but I didn't get help from them.
So, the Perl commands:

```
$temp=`/home/pi/spitest/RaspberryPi-mcp3008Spi/tempv1`;
print $temp;
```

display correctly the output of program **tempv1** when running from the linux console:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www/cgi-bin $ ls -la temp.pl
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 193 Apr 12 15:09 temp.pl
pi@raspberrypi /var/www/cgi-bin $ perl temp.pl 
Content-Type: text/plain

<html><body>20.4</body></html>pi@raspberrypi
```

but it does not display this specific output when I run it from my browser:

```
http://192.168.1.102/cgi-bin/temp.pl

output: <html><body></body></html>
```

My server is lighttpd and its user and group is both **www-data**.
It feels like it's a permission thing, but I'd like your opinion.

**SOLUTION EDIT:**
In the beginning I failed to see the connection with **/dev/spidev*** devices but now it's clear that the problem was there (file permissions). Thank you all for your help, and I am sorry for the initial misleading info:

My system command that I wanted to call from the Perl script used these spidev* devices to communicate with a chip. When I called this system command (application) from the CLI (user=pi) it ran fine, but when it was executed as part of the Perl script which was launched through the web server (user=www-data) the application failed, obviously because user www-data did not have access rights to /dev/spidev*.

My work-around was to chown the /dev/spidev* devices to www-data, but maybe I will have to find a more clean solution.

Too bad stackoverflow won't let me post this answer because I have low reputation.

Comment: Are those two lines the only things in your Perl program?

Comment: it has several other lines, but it starts with "#!/usr/bin/perl"

Comment: Can you `su` to www-data and see if you can run the script?

Comment: Execute like real executable, without perl.

Comment: $ ./tempv1
could not open SPI device: Permission denied

Comment: ok found the solution. The system command (program) I wanted to execute in the Perl script used an SPI device (/devf/spidev0.0), which the user pi from CLI has access to, but the user www-data has not.

Comment: I chowned the /dev/spidev* files to www-data and the problem is solved. Many thanks. PS: stackoverflow does not allow me to post my own answer cause of low reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What user is your web server running as? Check that user is able to run `/home/pi/spitest/RaspberryPi-mcp3008Spi/tempv1` (and change to the right directory).

Otherwise, you may find that looking in your web server error logs will tell you more about what's not working.

Comment: The server's user and group is both www-data. This user should have access to all directories and files with permissions -rwxrwxr-x or -rwxrwxr-x, right?

Comment: @user3526774 What you just said here does not really provide any useful feedback. We still do not know if your `tempv1` has the correct privileges set, and we do not know if you understood what was said. Ideally, you should have said "The tempv1 program has -rwxrwxr-x permissions, that should include www-data, right?"

Comment: @Sobrique one up for Sobrique because his answer made me see that executing the system command (application) from CLI does not imply the same user or the same permissions.

Comment: Chowning /dev can work, but it's probably not the best idea - you give your webserver user broad access to it. I'd suggest looking up how to configure sudo to give limited scope privileged access.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of problems such as these, is difference in relative paths. I have a tendency of using absolute paths for that reason.

In addition, it sounds to me like your subscript might be printing to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT`. Backticks only capture STDOUT, so you need to do a redirect with the help of `2>&1`

```
my @output = `scriptName 2>&1`;
```

**NB:** The redirect doesn't work with all shells (I believe it was tcsh that didn't support it back when i had a similar problem). Bash takes the redirect just fine.

Comment: my "subscript" is not a script, it's a program written in C++, compiled with g++ and outputs the text with a simple cout.

Comment: @Jarmund He is using an absolute path, and he is getting stdout output when running from the console.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your script doesn't have the correct Perl shebang as its first line since when you start it from the commandline you specify perl is the interpreter and it works, whereas your webserver doesn't seem to be running it under perl so it doesn't work.

Find where perl is with

```
which perl
```

then change the first line of your script to match the location, i.e. something like

```
#!/bin/perl
```

Your script should also output an HTML HEAD before the body, btw.

In fact, just edit your question and show us your script.

**ADDED**

How does your lighty config file look? Like this?

```
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "/cgi-bin/" {
      cgi.assign = ( ".pl" => "/usr/bin/perl" )
}
```

Comment: which perl outputs the correct shebang, which is "#!/usr/bin/perl" and I have already included it in my script

Comment: the second part isn't there, the block starting with "$HTTP". Should I  append it?

Comment: Yes, and then restart lighttpd.

Comment: I tried it but I have the same result. My absolute path to cgi-bin is /var/www/cgi-bin, should it matter?

Comment: Should be fine. Looks like you have a permissions problem on your SPI device /dev/spidev*, try "chmod 777 /dev/spi*"

Comment: Yes Mark, that exactly was the problem, but I failed to imagine the impact of /dev/spidev*, didn't even mention it on my problem description... gonna edit it now so it becomes clear to any other fellow.

Comment: Glad you are all working now. Thanks are due to @TLP and mpapec.